# how to use ngClass

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to change color of content to be red if element.maker == true else green
for this I did following but it only worked for first condition means red color appears but green can't

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of marketTradeHistoryArray ">
    <td [ngClass]="element.maker ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success1'"> {{element.price}} </td>
    <td [ngClass]="element.maker ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success1'"> {{element.quantity}} </td>
    <td [ngClass]="element.maker ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success1'">{{element.price * element.quantity}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: r u missing a [] brackets in second & third condition ?

Comment: Did you try `<td [ngClass]="{element.maker ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success1}'"> {{element.quantity}} </td>`?

Comment: I tried all of three methods {{}},[] and simple in quotes

Comment: The correct class name for green text is text-success, not text-success1.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me thanks all

```
  <tr *ngFor="let element of marketTradeHistoryArray ">
       <td [ngClass]=" (element.maker === 'true') ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success1'">{{element.price}}</td>
       <td [ngClass]=" (element.maker === 'true') ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success1'"> {{element.quantity}}  </td>
       <td [ngClass]=" (element.maker === 'true') ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success1'">{{element.price * element.quantity}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it like that:

```
<td [ngClass]="{'text-danger': element.maker, 'text-success1': !element.maker">...</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngClass like this :

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhzwub?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

@Muhammad Danish give a try to this,

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of marketTradeHistoryArray ">
    <td [ngClass]="{ element.maker ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success' }"> {{element.price}} </td>
    <td [ngClass]="{ element.maker ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success' }"> {{element.quantity}} </td>
    <td [ngClass]="{ element.maker ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success' }">{{element.price * element.quantity}}</td>
</tr>
```

have a look here for more details about [**`ngClass`**](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngclass-ngstyle/)